# Lanzar script desde botón html

Tags: javascript, java

Quiero llamar un js desde html-bootstrap pero lo ejecuta antes de llamarlo. Quiero hacer un botón que al darle clic lo mande a llamar y lo ejecute hasta que se le haya dado clic allí y no antes.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success"  onclick="+updateTC()+" name="boton" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" disabled>Aceptar</button>
```

y el método que quiero que ejecute al darle clic es este:

```
    private boolean updateTC()  {
        System.out.println("Entrooooooooooooooop" +" "+ usuarioID );
        Connection conn = null;
        conn = getConnection("megaqppedido");
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            sql.append(" UPDATE usuario ");
            sql.append(" SET tc = TRUE ");
            sql.append(" WHERE usuarioId = ? ");
            sql.append("   AND usuarioActivo IS TRUE ");
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
            pst.setInt(1, usuarioID);
            pst.executeUpdate();
        }catch(SQLException ex)
        {
            log.error("Se genero un error al desactivar el usuario",ex);
            closeConnection(pst, rs);
            return false;
        }
        finally {
            closeConnection(pst, rs);
            sql = null;
        }
        
        System.out.println("SALIÓ" +" "+ usuarioID );
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Eso es un js o un java? *Hola quiero llamar un js desde html-bootstrap*

Comment: Es un metodo java que quiero mandar a llamar desde un js

Comment: Aqui dicen que no es posible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536455/calling-java-method-in-javascript  (no tengo ni idea, la verdad, es la primera vez que veo que alguien lo intenta así... quizas con ajax te saldria algo?)

Comment: Soy nuevo en esto o alguna recomendación para que el botón guarde en BD?? y ya no se muestre ese modal?

Comment: No se java, pero si se trata de actualizar una base de datos yo lo haria con PHP y ajax seguramente dado tu escenario actual. Pero para ayudarte con eso debes intentarlo tu primero, pues aqui corregimos errores, no hacemos código a medida, lo siento.  Aún así, como decia, desconozco java y quizas si es posible invocarlo desde peticiones ajax (seguramente si, si eso tiene servidor propio).

Comment: Bootstrap acá no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta, tampoco el IDE (Eclipse). ¿Cómo es que estás usando Java Web? ¿Con qué framework? ¿Por qué querés mezclar Java con Javascript?

Comment: te recomiendo seguir este tutorial para hacerlo con dukescript: http://www.dukescript.com/best/practices/2016/01/26/jpa-and-dukescript.html

Comment: Si utilizo Eclipse como IDE Y no utilizo ahorita ningun framework es un proyecto que ya estaba hecho solo le estoy agregando nuevas opciones y solo que quieren utilizar BD (Postgresql) para ese banner (modal) y que no se le muestre al cliente